# When using ggraph for an igraph network, I get "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "x", value = numeric(0)) : "

Tags: r, igraph, ggraph

I'm working with egocentric network data.  I first created an egor object like this:

```
egor.obj <- egor::threefiles_to_egor(egos= ego.df, 
                                     alters.df= alter.attr.all, 
                                     edges= alter_ties, 
                                     ID.vars = list(ego = "networkCanvasEgoUUID", 
                                                    alter = "networkCanvasUUID", 
                                                    source = "networkCanvasSourceUUID", 
                                                    target = "networkCanvasTargetUUID"))
```

And then converted it into a list of igraph networks like this:

```
gr.list <- egor::as_igraph(egor.obj)
```

I'm trying to graph just one of those networks.  So I used the egoID to pull out just one:

```
(gr.examp <- gr.list[["0012601c-c2b1-4881-ab25-b2a115f4530c"]])
```

And then tried visualizing it:

```
set.seed(607)
ggraph(gr.examp) + 
  geom_edge_link() + 
  geom_node_point(size=5, color="blue") + 
  theme_graph(base_family = 'Helvetica')
```

It gives me the following output and error:

> Using `stress` as default layout
> New names:
> • `from` -> `from...1`
> • `to` -> `to...2`
> • `from` -> `from...4`
> • `to` -> `to...5`
> New names:
> • `from` -> `from...1`
> • `to` -> `to...2`
> • `from` -> `from...4`
> • `to` -> `to...5`
> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "x", value = numeric(0)) :
> replacement has 0 rows, data has 20

Can you help me figure out why it doesn't work?

I have checked that the graph isn't empty.  It has 10 vertices and 20 edges, and when I do a simple plot with plot(gr.examp) it looks fine.